# Need C library that implements set operations

Tags: c, set

I'm looking for a C library (not C++) that implements set operations. I need to support the following operations:

- intersection
- union
- elementOf
- isSubset
- insert (add to set)
- clone
- equals

Could I just use the libc binary tree routines?

Answer (score 3):

I haven't used it myself, but [pblSet](http://www.mission-base.com/peter/source/pbl/doc/set.html) looks solid.